# Como mostro o resultado de uma conta realizada em um iFrame no documento original?

Tags: javascript, html

Fiz um iFrame que mostra produtos de outro arquivo .html, lá é realizado um produto do preço do produto e a quantidade selecionada com o resultado desse produto mostrando lá mesmo.

No entando, eu gostaria de pegar os valores de todos esses resultados, somar tudo e mostrar o total fora desse iFrame, no documento original.

Preciso disso para outro projeto, onde eu irei colocar novas categorias de produtos em `src`'s diferentes do mesmo iFrame, com o total de todos no primeiro documento.

Segue o código:

HTML (Página onde está o iFrame)

```
<body>
<iframe src="outro.html" frameborder="0" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
<p>Total: R$<span id="total">0</span></p>
</body>
```

HTML (Página que é `src` do iFrame)

```
<body>
    <div class="itens">
        <p id="topo">Produto 1</p>
        <p id="tipo">Tipo: <b>Brinquedo</b></p>
        <p id="pre">Preço: <b>R$50</b></p><br>
        <p id="qtd">Quantidade:<br><input type="number" id="qtd" min="0" max="99" value="0" onmouseup="calc(this.value, 'brinquedo', 50)">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="tot">Total: <br>R$<span id="brinquedo" name="valor">0</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="itens">
        <p id="topo">Produto 2</p>
        <p id="tipo">Tipo: <b>Brinquedo</b></p>
        <p id="pre">Preço: <b>R$100</b></p><br>
        <p id="qtd">Quantidade:<br><input type="number" id="qtd" min="0" max="99" value="0" onmouseup="calc(this.value, 'brinquedo2', 100)">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="tot">Total: <br>R$<span id="brinquedo2" name="valor">0</span></p>
      </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript (Função que eu utilizei pro cálculo)

```js
let total = 0;
function calc(q, v, t){
    total = (q * t)
    document.getElementById(v).innerHTML = total;
    calc_total()
}

function calc_total(){
   
    let b1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('brinquedo').innerHTML);
    let b2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('brinquedo2').innerHTML);
    
    valTotal = b1 + b2

    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = valTotal

}
```

Comment: O cálculo é feito no iframe ou no documento original? 

Comment: O cálculo é feito no iFrame

Comment: Tente `window.parent.document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = valTotal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `parent` para acessar funções que estejam na página pai do Iframe. Por exemplo:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="outro.html" frameborder="0" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>
        <p>Total: R$<span id="total">0</span></p>

        <script>
            function set_total(valTotal){
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = valTotal
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**outro.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="itens">
            <p id="topo">Produto 1</p>
            <p id="tipo">Tipo: <b>Brinquedo</b></p>
            <p id="pre">Preço: <b>R$50</b></p><br>
            <p id="qtd">Quantidade:<br><input type="number" id="qtd" min="0" max="99" value="0" onmouseup="calc(this.value, 'brinquedo', 50)">&nbsp;</p>
            <p id="tot">Total: <br>R$<span id="brinquedo" name="valor">0</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="itens">
            <p id="topo">Produto 2</p>
            <p id="tipo">Tipo: <b>Brinquedo</b></p>
            <p id="pre">Preço: <b>R$100</b></p><br>
            <p id="qtd">Quantidade:<br><input type="number" id="qtd" min="0" max="99" value="0" onmouseup="calc(this.value, 'brinquedo2', 100)">&nbsp;</p>
            <p id="tot">Total: <br>R$<span id="brinquedo2" name="valor">0</span></p>
        </div>

        <script>
            let total = 0;
                function calc(q, v, t){
                    total = (q * t)
                    document.getElementById(v).innerHTML = total;
                    calc_total()
                }
                function calc_total(){
                    let b1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('brinquedo').innerHTML);
                    let b2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('brinquedo2').innerHTML);
                    var valTotal = b1 + b2
                    parent.set_total(valTotal); // <- aqui eu chamo a função declarada em index.html, passando o valor total como parâmetro
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**OBSERVAÇÃO**

Se você tentar rodar isso colocando o caminho do arquivo `index.html` no Chrome, irá dar errado, porque ele irá bloquear essa ação como descrito [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983786/blocked-a-frame-of-origin-null-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame-chrome). Por isso, você precisa testar em algum servidor, seja ele local (como XAMPP, ou qualquer outro) ou na web mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo! Funcionou muito bem aqui. Também não fazia ideia deste bloqueio.

Comment: Agora vou testar no projeto real para ver se cola também.

Comment: Funcionou, amigo! Obrigado.